# How to tell which .wav files will be compatible with Java?

Tags: java, swing, wav, javasound, audio-player

**EDIT--** I discovered that if I use the "CircusSong" wav file for button clicks, it starts to play. So, the other files I'm trying to access must not be compatible. How can I figure out which formats of .wav files will work?

**NOTE:** Every audio file I've tried plays on my machine (Ubuntu). They're just not being recognized by IntelliJ.

I have this sound file that plays while the program runs (until I stop the Thread). I was able to successfully add it to a "Sounds" folder within my "src" folder.

**NOTE:** I'm just now learning how to use sound files.If I go to the file in IntelliJ, here is what it looks like:

[image: Circus Music Song]

Well, I want one more sound in the program, and I've tried two thus far with no luck. When I hover over the error, I get "class or interface expected":

[image: Another Sound File]

Here is what is used for these two files:

**Field Declaration and Sound Clip Methods:**

```
public class SimManager implements SimulationEventListener, LineListener {
    File mainMusicThemeSong = new File("src/Sounds/CircusSong.wav");
    File selectionSound = new File("src/Sounds/SelectionSound.wav");
    public static Clip mainClip;
    public static Clip selectionClip;

public void playSelectionSound() {
        try {
            Line.Info linfo = new Line.Info(Clip.class);
            Line line = AudioSystem.getLine(linfo);
            selectionClip = (Clip) line;
            selectionClip.addLineListener(this);
            AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(selectionSound);
            selectionClip.open(audioIn);
            selectionClip.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR WHILE PLAYING SOUND CLIP");
        }
    }
    public void playMainThemeSong() {
        try {
            Line.Info linfo = new Line.Info(Clip.class);
            Line line = AudioSystem.getLine(linfo);
            mainClip = (Clip) line;
            mainClip.addLineListener(this);
            AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(mainMusicThemeSong);
            mainClip.open(audioIn);
            mainClip.start();
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR PLAYING MUSIC CLIP");
        }

    }
```

Then, also within that class, I determine which sound is played. The main theme is played once "Run" is clicked. The other sound is supposed to be played when all the other buttons are selected, but I'm only showing the "NORMAL_SETUP_EVENT" so there's not a lot of unnecessary code.

```
public void simulationEventOccurred(SimulationEvent simulationEvent)  {

if (simulationEvent.getEventType() == SimulationEvent.NORMAL_SETUP_EVENT) {
    playSelectionSound(); // <-- THIS DOESN"T WORK
    colonySim.initializeAntColony(); // INITIALIZE NORMALLY
    antSimGUI.setTime(time);
}
if (simulationEvent.getEventType() == SimulationEvent.RUN_EVENT) {

    isMoving = false;
    thisThread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {

            playMainThemeSong(); //<-- THIS WORKS
            mainClip.loop(-1); //<-- THIS LOOPS UNTIL THREAD STOPS
            newTurn(); // START INCREMENTING THROUGH TURNS
        }
    };
    thisThread.start();
}
```

So, do I just have incompatible files? Because I don't see any error in my code since the main theme song file works just fine. Why is the formatting of my .wav files not being recognized?

Here is the stack trace:

```
    COULDN'T PLAY SOUND CLIP
javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: could not get audio input stream from input file
    at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioSystem.java:1189)
    at SimManager.simulationEventOccurred(SimManager.java:131)
    at AntSimGUI.fireSimulationEvent(AntSimGUI.java:193)
    at AntSimGUI$ControlPanel$ButtonHandler.actionPerformed(AntSimGUI.java:407)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: IntelliJ wants and expects you to place non-source resource files outside of the `src` folder, as this is general practice with Java. It'd be customary to create a `res` or other resource folder at the same level as the source folder, as the source folder is meant for code to be compiled.

Comment: @Vulcan I think I understand that, but why does the first sound work fine?

Comment: @Vulcan It was customary to place resource in `src` for many years, till Maven came along and some senior devs decided otherwise, Intellij (like most IDEs) tend to "encourage" a particular ethos/psudo standard on developers which isn't always helpful. Having said that, I believe the preferred "standard" is `resource`, but this comes down the prefered project structure

Comment: When you say "doesn't work" do you mean it throws an exception or just doesn't play?

Comment: It just goes straight to the catch print statment on the console - "ERROR PLAYING SOUND CLIP". The rest of the program will still run, that particular sound (as well as every other sound I've tried thus far) won't play.

Comment: I need to emphasize that the first sound (the gameplay song) plays just fine. Any other sound does not play when I click other buttons when specified.

Comment: You should print the exception's trace to get detailed information.

Comment: I'll edit my question and include it. I added "e.printStackTrace()" to my code

Comment: 1) Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL. 2) WAV is a container format. Some encodings that might be used within the container can be handled by Java Sound, while others cannot.

Comment: *"How to tell which .wav files will be compatible with Java?"* Try loading/playing them in a Java app.  There are also a lot of sound editing tools that will tell you the internal format.

Comment: I downloaded a total of 13 sounds over the course of 2 days. Out of those 13 sounds, only one of them worked. I wrote a small, separate Java app that only opens and plays a file. The files were working, so I'm starting to think it was my code rather than the file itself. Is it relevant that I was using the Thread class to run the program?

Comment: Just in case you overlooked it, using a URL is really the safest way to go, rather than using a FileName, as Andrew points out above. Did you try it? File name do not work for audio files that are within jars, but URLs do. If IntelliJ is doing anything tricky, the file subsystem within it may be virtual and not readable by the operating system as a normal file (i.e., from outside of IntelliJ).